# v_R_System is missing operatingSystemVersion0 column

Tags: sccm

Recently setup a new 2016 SCCM server and we had a query that had worked in the past to get the devices but, when we run the SQL query we are getting an error that the 'operatingSystemVersion0' column doesn't exist. Expanded v_R_System and that column is not available.

If we run the same query against the 2012 SCCM instance there are no issues. Is this column in a different location for SCCM 2016?

```sql
SELECT Name0,Distinguished_Name0,Operating_System_Name_and0,operatingSystemVersion0,Is_Virtual_Machine0,Last_Logon_Timestamp0,Full_Domain_Name0,User_Domain0,Active0 
FROM v_R_System
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could find it in view v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM. Try the following SQL Query.

```
SELECT v_R_System.Name0,Distinguished_Name0,Operating_System_Name_and0,Version0,Is_Virtual_Machine0,Last_Logon_Timestamp0,Full_Domain_Name0,User_Domain0,Active0 
FROM v_R_System inner join v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM on v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID
```

Best Regards,
Ray